# collectionview with swipe in view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm doing a simple image gallery with a collectionview listing my images. Images names are stocked into an array. When I press on an image, it display the picture in a view controller with an imageview.

Now I would like to be able to switch from one image to the next and previous image with a swipe instead of going back to the collection view to change picture. Did I choose a wrong way to achieve my project or is there an easy way to do this?

Thank you already for your help!

Nicolas.

Here's my actual code :

PhotosCollectionViewController.h

## import

```
@interface PhotosCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController
{
    NSArray *photosArray;
}
@end
```

PhotosCollectionViewController.m

```
#import "PhotosCollectionViewController.h"
#import "PhotoDetailViewController.h"

@interface PhotosCollectionViewController ()

@end

@implementation PhotosCollectionViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    photosArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"angry_birds_cake.jpg", @"creme_brelee.jpg", @"egg_benedict.jpg", @"full_breakfast.jpg", @"green_tea.jpg", @"ham_and_cheese_panini.jpg", @"ham_and_egg_sandwich.jpg", @"hamburger.jpg", @"instant_noodle_with_egg.jpg", @"japanese_noodle_with_pork.jpg", @"mushroom_risotto.jpg", @"noodle_with_bbq_pork.jpg", @"starbucks_coffee.jpg", @"thai_shrimp_cake.jpg", @"vegetable_curry.jpg", @"white_chocolate_donut.jpg", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return photosArray.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *photosImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    photosImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[photosArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushPhoto"]) {
        NSArray *indexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
        PhotoDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [indexPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        destViewController.photoName = [photosArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}

@end
```

PhotoDetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PhotoDetailViewController : UIViewController


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *photoImageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *photoName;
@end
```

PhotoDetailViewController.m

```
#import "PhotoDetailViewController.h"

@interface PhotoDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation PhotoDetailViewController
@synthesize photoImageView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.photoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.photoName];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right.Pass the array of images(or urls) and on the next and previous button action(or gesture recogonizer) , load the images from the array and show in the viewcontroller.

Create an array instance "imageArray" in the DetailsedImageVC class
stackedImages be the array in which the images are available

```
DetailedImageVC *vc=[[DetailedImageVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailedImageVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    vc.imageArray=self.stackedImages ;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Now you have the array in DetailedImageVC and now on,when the next image needed action just get the image from the array nd load

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll try this and come back with my code if I'm lost. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm hold with something. I don't understand how to pass NSArray... can you help me again?

Comment: If you are using seague.tehn use the seague methods to set the value in next viewcontroller

Comment: I'm okay to send the name of the selected item to the view controller and display the corresponding picture with the segue. But when I try to send a NSArray I really don't understand the process. I'm sorry but I'm a noob. I put this in my segue : [destViewController setPhotoArray:photosArray]; and this in my viewcontroller :     photoArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:photosArray];
But it doesn't work. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just enable user interaction for your `UIImageView`, attach a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` with the direction configured to how you want, and change the image in the `UIImageView` in the selector you've set in the gesture recogniser.